# How to set a pointer to struct to NULL

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization

```
typedef struct _DocumentRow
{
    char * code /** The code */;
    char * designation /** The designation */;
    double quantity /** The quantity */;
    char * unity /** The unity */;
    double basePrice /** The base price */;
    double sellingPrice /** The selling price */;
    double discount /** The discount */;
    double rateOfVAT /** The rate of VAT */;
    struct _DocumentRow * next /** The pointer to the next row */;
} DocumentRow;

void DocumentRowList_init(DocumentRow ** list) {
    DocumentRow *L;
    list = ( DocumentRow ** ) malloc( sizeof( DocumentRow* ) );
    if ( list == NULL ) {
        fatalError( "memory is not enough" );
    }
    L = NULL;
    list = &L;
}
```

After using the function `DocumentRowList_init`, when I test `if ( *list == NULL )`, it evaluates to false, why ? I have already set `list = &L` and `L = NULL`.

Comment: don't follow you question...  if *list==NULL returns 0, *list is not NULL.

Comment: `list` is local. `*list = L;` to set.

Comment: To me, this code seems to do nothing, e.g. `L = NULL; list = &L;`?!

Comment: also `L = malloc( sizeof( DocumentRow ) );` `if(L == NULL) ...`

Comment: What you wrote is called a memory leak. You allocate memory pointed by `list` and then you make `list` to point somewhere else. You will not be able to `free(list)`. And `*list` is not `NULL` because `*list` is `L` which is a pointer to `NULL`. Outside this function, testing `*list` may result in a segmentation fault.

Comment: set to NULL `void DocumentRowList_init(DocumentRow ** list) { *list = NULL; }`,

Comment: some other minor points in your code: (1) identifiers starting with `_` and a capital letter are reserved, you shouldn't use them. Here it is compiletely sufficient to use the same identifier as `struct` tag as for the `typedef`. (2) don't cast the return of `malloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to change (initialize) something pointed to by `list`, here is how it usually be done:

```
void DocumentRowList_init(DocumentRow ** list) {
    *list = ( DocumentRow * ) malloc( sizeof( DocumentRow ) );
    if ( *list == NULL ) {
        fatalError( "memory is not enough" );
    }
}
```

Comment: You malloc only `size(DocumentRow*)` bytes for a pointer, not `size(DocumentRow)` for the struct. In this case the type cast to `( DocumentRow ** )` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You would have undefined behaviour here. `L` is a local variable, so when you return it's address via the pointer pointer, the variable no longer exists when `DocumentRowList_init` is returning.

So even though you assign `NULL` to it, it will point to invalid memory.

But `list` is local to `DocumentRowList_init`, so it will not return the value anyway, as you only assign it a value and then return.

If you want to return a structure of `DocumentRow` you'd have to use this

```
  *list = malloc( sizeof *L);
```

to allocate a structure and return the pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
void DocumentRowList_init(DocumentRow ** list) {
    DocumentRow *L;
    list = ( DocumentRow ** ) malloc( sizeof( DocumentRow* ) );
    if ( list == NULL ) {
        fatalError( "memory is not enough" );
    }
    L = NULL;
    list = &L;
}
```

Please mind that list=&L assigns list the address of a variable located on the stack. So once you exist the function the variable is out of scope and your list is left pointing to a some location (on the stack).

Comment: So, what can I do ? I want to make *list = NULL, but it also can't work

Comment: you can make DocumentRow *L  a global variable; or dynamically allocate memory for L: L= (DocumentRow *)malloc(sizeof(DocumentRow *))